# What is the difference between Bhagavan and Devata?

Tags: identification-request

Is there any difference between Bhagavan and Devata Please give some examples who is called as Bhagavan and who is called as Devata.

Comment: God has created many yonies (species) like humans, animals, devas, gandharvas, plants ect. Devas is one of God's created yoni. Some refers devas as demi-gods. People who does good deeds got deva yonies and enters in heaven.